# Tie instances of a class to another, aside from making one an inner class?

Tags: java

I'm writing a simulation with various components, some dynamic. The most logical structure would be something like this:

```
class Simulation {
  int getSimulationTime() {
    ...
  }
  class Thing1 {
    ...
  }
  class Thing2 {
    ...
  }

  Container <Thing1> box1;
  Container <Thing2> box2;
  ...
  void addThing1(Thing1 thing) {
     box1.add(thing);
  }
  Thing1 getThing1() {
     return box1.getOne();
  }
  ...
}
```

There are at least two nice things about this structure:

1. The `Thing1`s and `Thing2`s have access to the simulation time without having to explicitly carry around their `Simulation`s.
2. The type system will ensure that I don't accidentally mix up components of two different simulations: if I write `simulation1.addThing1(simulation2.getThing1());` the compiler will (correctly) reject it because the `Thing1` produced is not the same type as the `Thing1` demanded.

#### The problem

The actual `Thing1` and `Thing2` class definitions are much too large for me to want to shove into the `Simulation` class, and Java doesn't allow inner class definitions to be pulled out into separate files. Is there an alternative way to accomplish these objectives?

#### A partial solution

I just realized that I can probably use Generics to help with the second part of this, at least
externally, by using an inner class to give each instance of the simulation a distinct type identity:

```
class Simulation {
   class Identity {
      Identity(){}
   }
   Container<Thing1<Identity>> box1;
   Thing1<Identity> getThing1() {
      return box1.getOne();
   }
   void addThing1(Thing1<Identity> thing1) {
      box1.add(thing1);
   }
}

class Thing1<ID> {
   ...
}
```

Now if I attempt `simulation1.addThing1(simulation2.getOne())` I will get an error because the relevant `Thing1`s again have different types. This solution is, however, less than pretty, and doesn't take care of visibility so nicely.

Comment: there is no exact alternative for inner class but you can keep the Thing1 and Thing2 into 2 separate classes and use a method inside Simulation class to create them and access the simulation attributes within that method and you can inject them to these Thing classes objects...its indirect way of achieving what inner class achieves...

Comment: I would say encapsulate the instances of Thing1 and Thing2 so that your simulation class creates and manages them, but function calls can convince the simulation to do things to them.  That way you get the benefits of the inner class without having it all in one file.  It also allows you to use the same thing1 and thing2 class files for other classes.